# Oferecer recompensa como pontuação extra

Tags: debate, recompensa

Em 24 horas poderia e ia oferecer uma recompensa à minha questão, então, mesmo que minha questão já tenha uma resposta satisfatória, eu posso oferecer uma recompensa e marcar a resposta como aceita, como forma de pontuação extra para uma resposta como forma de agradecimento além dos pontos de aceitação?

Comment: Pode, na hora de escolher a justificativa da recompensa tem até uma opção pensada pra isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto, não sabia, será minha primeira vez :)

Comment: Nem sabia que podia oferecer recompensa após ter uma resposta aceita, nunca tinha reparado... Vou marcar a resposta e depois dou a recompensa.

Comment: Desistiu? Aproveitando: depois de "setar" a recompensa, tem um período que você tem de esperar antes de escolher quem ganha os pontos (acho que é 24h no mínimo).

Comment: @bfavaretto, não desisti não, é que ainda não está liberado para oferecer a recompensa, só marquei como resolvido pra não deixar aberta, mas assim que liberar eu vou recompensar.

Comment: Esbanjou nos quinhentão, hein, Papa? :D A resposta parece pro pacaramba, certamente merece. Dica: deixa para dar a recompensa até o último momento, assim tem mais chance de + + + + na pergunta/respostas.

Comment: @brasofilo, ostentação rs. Ia oferecer uma recompensa se não tivesse resposta... Como a resposta caiu como uma luva e ainda foi explicada, achei que merecia os 500ão :) Tem mais 6 dias ainda rs